# Problema al unir dos listas para crear un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola tengo un problema al usar zip para unir dos listas.

(El codigo toma la lista de una db pero voy a crear la lista directamente, no hay ninguna diferencia ya que si se imprime desde la db da los mismos resultados)

```
lista1 = ['60baa2ec71633957586f0f4a', '60baa2f671633957586f0f4b', '60baa2fe71633957586f0f4c', '60baa30071633957586f0f4d', '60baa30a71633957586f0f4e', '60baa31471633957586f0f4f']
lista2 = ['E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E']

dic = (dict(zip(list2, list1)))
print(dic)
```

esto se supone que me debe entregar un diccionario bien hecho, pero me imprime es esto.

```
{'E': '60baa31471633957586f0f4f', 'C': '60baa2fe71633957586f0f4c', 'D': '60baa30071633957586f0f4d'}
```

No solo no une todos los items si no que lo hace en un orden incorrecto.

Comment: Revisa tu código. En el `zip` usas variables no definidas en el código.

Comment: lo que pasa es que los valores de las claves se reemplazan, esto por ser iguales

Comment: No no, perdon, eso fue de mi codigo, ya esta bien, pero igual da el error

Comment: necesitas que las claves sean las letras?

Comment: Si, necesito que sea Letra: ID

Comment: Un diccionario **no admite duplicados**. Por ejemplo, cuando lee la letra E, de primeras almacena `60baa2ec71633957586f0f4a`. Cuando lee la segunda E, como no admite duplicados, sustituye el primero por `60baa30a71633957586f0f4e`. Y cuando lee la tercera E, sustituye otra vez por `60baa31471633957586f0f4f`. Lo mismo para la letra C.

Comment: muy bien mi querido L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno como dije lo que pasa es que el valor se esta sobre escribiendo pues las claves se repiten, intenta hacer esto:

```py
dic = {"E":2,"B":3,"E":1}

print(dic)
```

Y veras como resultado esto:

```
{'E': 1, 'B': 3}
```

La solución que propongo que es crees un diccionario de listas, es decir los valores serán listas:

```py
dic = {} #creamos nuestro diccionario

#iteramos 
for v,k in zip(lista1,lista2):
    if k not in dic.keys():
        dic[k] =[v] #creamos la clave si no existe
    else:
        dic[k].append(v) #añadimos a la lista si la clave existe
```

Esto dará como resultado:

```
{'E': ['60baa2ec71633957586f0f4a', 
       '60baa30a71633957586f0f4e', 
       '60baa31471633957586f0f4f'],
'C': ['60baa2f671633957586f0f4b', 
      '60baa2fe71633957586f0f4c'], 
'D': ['60baa30071633957586f0f4d']}
```

Otra solución podría ser invertir el orden, es decir que las claveas sea los valores de `lista1`, sin embargo esto implicaría que si quieres hacer una búsqueda de los valors lo hagas de forma diferente

```py
dic = {k:v for k,[v] in zip(lista1,lista2)}
print(dic)
```

**Resultado**

```
{'60baa2ec71633957586f0f4a': 'E', 
'60baa2f671633957586f0f4b': 'C', 
'60baa2fe71633957586f0f4c': 'C', 
'60baa30071633957586f0f4d': 'D', 
'60baa30a71633957586f0f4e': 'E', 
'60baa31471633957586f0f4f': 'E'}
```

Comment: Oh vale, supongo que lo mejor sera cambiar el orden, gracias.